# How can I fix classifier model fitting error for Handwritten character recognition using CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My

```
model.fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
```

method has an error.

I am stuck in this for long. I did a lot of Google search/youtube search but couldn't solve it.
If my

```
 x=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test',
        target_size=(28, 28),  
        batch_size=batch_size,
        classes =_classes,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

then

1. what should be the data structure of y?
2. How about other parameters?

My error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-39aa67ba47fc> in <module>
----> 1 classifier.fit(train_set, epochs = 10,validation_data = test_set, validation_steps = 90) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1181                 _r=1):    1182            callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)    1184               if data_handler.should_sync:    1185                 context.async_wait() ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

path="data/train"
_classes = os.listdir(path)

batch_size = 41
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train', 
        target_size=(28, 28), 
        batch_size=batch_size,
        classes =_classes,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation', 
        target_size=(28, 28), 
        batch_size=batch_size,
        classes =_classes,
        class_mode='categorical')


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test', 
        target_size=(28, 28), 
        batch_size=batch_size,
        classes =_classes,
        class_mode='categorical')

classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (28, 28, 1)))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(.2))

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(.2))

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Dropout(.2))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(.2))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(.2))

classifier.add(Dense(units = 48, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()


classifier_json = classifier.to_json()
with open("ocr.json","w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(classifier_json)

classifier.save_weights("ocr.h5")


import csv
col_list = ["Class", "Label","Devanagari Label","Phonetics"]
df = pd.read_csv("labels.csv", usecols=col_list) #df=DataFrame
translitration_label=df["Label"].tolist()
translitration_label_dict=df["Label"]
devanagari_class=df["Class"].tolist()
devanagari_class_dict=df["Class"]
devanagari_label=df["Devanagari Label"].tolist()
devanagari_label_dict=df["Devanagari Label"]


print(train_set)
#gives <tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x0000021ECCE0E190>

classifier.fit(train_set, epochs = 10,validation_data = test_set, validation_steps = 90)
```

The _classes are:
['c1', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15', 'c16', 'c17', 'c18', 'c19', 'c2', 'c20', 'c21', 'c22', 'c23', 'c24', 'c25', 'c26', 'c27', 'c28', 'c29', 'c3', 'c30', 'c31', 'c32', 'c33', 'c34', 'c35', 'c36', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'v1', 'v10', 'v11', 'v12', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9']

If I do,

```
print(devanagari_label)
print(translitration_label)
```

it gives,

['क', 'ख', 'ग', 'घ', 'ङ', 'च', 'छ', 'ज', 'झ', 'ञ', 'ट', 'ठ', 'ड', 'ढ', 'ण', 'त', 'थ', 'द', 'ध', 'न', 'प', 'फ', 'ब', 'भ', 'म', 'य', 'र', 'ल', 'व', 'श', 'ष', 'स', 'ह', 'क्ष', 'त्र', 'ज्ञ', 'अ', 'आ', 'इ', 'ई', 'उ', 'ऊ', 'ए', 'ऐ', 'ओ', 'औ', 'अं', 'अः']
['ka', 'kha', 'ga', 'gha', 'kna', 'cha', 'chha', 'ja', 'jha', 'yna', 'ta', 'tha', 'da', 'dha', 'ana', 'taa', 'thaa', 'daa', 'dhaa', 'na', 'pa', 'pha', 'ba', 'dha', 'ma', 'ya', 'ra', 'la', 'va', 'motosaw', 'petchiryosaw', 'patalosaw', 'ha', 'ksha', 'tra', 'gya', 'a', 'aa', 'i', 'ee', 'u', 'oo', 'ae', 'ai', 'o', 'au', 'an', 'ah']

The source of data is :
https://www.kaggle.com/ashokpant/devanagari-character-dataset
But I had modified it using a C# console program (since I am fluent in C# but not in Python) to fit my needs as:

Folder Structure of data/train, data/test, data/validation:
[image: folder structure]

each class inside data/train contains 164 images.
each class inside data/test contains 20 images.
each class inside data/validation contains 21 images.

Please help.

Comment: You have to provide more information about your data ( features, labels) and parts of your code that can help other users to reproduce or understand the errors.

Comment: @TouYou Sure. I will edit question.

Comment: I did respond to another question in the past where a similar dataset was consumed, would you mind checking [Devanagari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795896/how-to-input-user-images-to-predict-with-tensorflow/67814924#67814924) ? if that does not help, then pls post the dataset source.

Comment: @BigYan glad that it helped, you are welcome!